# touchlisteners and textviews

Tags: android, view, ontouchlistener

Actually I'm trying to implement an ontouchlistener into my android (1.5) application. 
therefore i implemented the "ontouchlistener" into the class, and then i put my code into the:

```
public boolean onTouchEvent (MotionEvent e){
 //code
}
```

The problem is, that if I am dragging over an (e.g.) Spinner or EditTextView than this Method isn't called. The only way to solve this which i figured out is to add an ontouchlistener to each of this views manually:

```
((Spinner)(findViewById(R.id.spinner1))).setOnTouchListener(tl);
((Spinner)(findViewById(R.id.spinner2))).setOnTouchListener(tl);
```

(tl is the ontouchlistener)
So isn't there a way to catch the touch event before it gets to each of those views?
thanks in advance

Ripei

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What exactly do you want to do - do you want to:

- *Detect whole gestures in some
  `Activity`.*
- *Detect touches only for a given
  `View`*

**If you want the former:**

Take a look at this example:
[Fling gesture detection on grid layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/937313/android-basic-gesture-detection).

Basically, you redirect all registered touch events to a `GestureDetector`.
It understands what exactly is the user input (single tap, double tap, scroll, etc.) and calls the corresponding callback in a `SimpleOnGestureListener`, which you should implement.

**If you want the latter:**

You can either:

1. Override the View's `onTouchEvent()`.
2. Implement and hook `onTouchListener` (if you want to get the touch before it's dispatched to it).

If you want to implement `onTouchListener`, you'll be doing your work not in the `onTouchEvent()` method, but in the interface's `onTouch()` method.

Hope that helps.

Comment: yes i want the first point you mentioned. but i am searching for a way to solve this without having to add a gesturelistener/onclicklistener to each view i add to the activity. 
but it seems like this isn't posisble.

Comment: No, actually the first approach I mentioned is exactly what you want - take a look at the examples in the link. Basically, you redirect all touches from your `Activity` to a `GestureDetector`. This means that all touches, that aren't internally handled in your views, are catched and scanned, so that you know if the user has double-tapped or scrolled. The `SimpleOnGestureListener` is registered to your `GestureDetector`, which is responsible for the whole `Activity`. You don't add listeners for each and every `View`.